# all objects in array are updating with same value while pushing the object with unique id into an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

on calling `pushValue()` function each time generating unique id by calling `getGUID()` after that assigning to `objectJson.id` and pushing to array but in `console.log()` it displays all object with same unique id.

```
<button onclick="pushValue()">
Click
</button>
<p id='displayjson'>
</p>

<script>
var arrayJson = [];
var objectJson =    {
                      name: "New Widget",
                      sizeX: 4,
                      sizeY: 1,
                      lib: 'fsf',
                      id:""
                                    };

  var pushValue = function(){
        objectJson.id = getGUID();     
        arrayJson.push(objectJson);
      document.getElementById("displayjson").innerText = JSON.stringify(arrayJson);     
        console.log(arrayJson);
   }                 

function getGUID() {
    //DOCS : -http://guid.us/GUID/JavaScript
    function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
        var guid = ('svg_id_' + S4() + S4() + "_" + S4() + "_4" + S4().substr(0, 3) + "_" + S4() + "_" +                   S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
  return guid;
}
</script>
```

click on this link https://jsfiddle.net/Akkikumar77/noLhzbwr/

Comment: Thats because your pushing references to the same object instead of creating new ones

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bdfnnL7j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you push the `objectJson` **reference** to the array. So if you change the object, it changes in every occurence. To avoid this, you need to clone the object before pushing to the array with `Object.assign()`

```
arrayJson.push(Object.assign({}, objectJson));
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noLhzbwr/1/).

Comment: thankyou D. Simon. it's working and also i thank you for making me aware of cloning concept.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing same object each time, so you are pushing that object only (a reference) not newly created object. Make a simple factory function and you're good to go. Or clone the object.

```
var arrayJson = [];
var createObject = function(){
return{
    name: "New Widget",
    sizeX: 4,
    sizeY: 1,
    lib: 'fsf',
    id: getGUID()
 }
}

var pushValue = function(){

    arrayJson.push(createObject());
  document.getElementById("displayjson").innerText = JSON.stringify(arrayJson);     
    console.log(objectJson);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is as a result of mutation.

Each time you call `objectJSON.id = getGUID()` you change the id value of the original `objectJSON`.

To stop referencing the original `objectJSON` object you use the `concat` method which makes a deep copy of it as opposed to using the `push` method.

Like this

`arrayJson.concat([objectJSON]);`

instead of

`arrayJson.push(objectJson);`

Answer (score 0):

You were changing the object, not duplicating it or creating a new one.  Here's one way to do it using most of your code:

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/KempoMan/tctw3buq/)

```
<button onclick="pushValue()">
Click
</button>
<p id='displayjson'>
</p>

<script>
var arrayJson = [];
var objectJson =    {
                      name: "New Widget",
                      sizeX: 4,
                      sizeY: 1,
                      lib: 'fsf',
                      id:"",
                                    };

  function CreateObject(name, id){
    this.name = name;
    this.sizeX = 4;
    this.sizeY = 1;
    this.lib = 'fsf';
        this.id = id;
  }       
  var pushValue = function(){
    var myNewObject = new CreateObject('someName', getGUID());

        arrayJson.push(myNewObject);
      document.getElementById("displayjson").innerText = JSON.stringify(arrayJson);     
        console.log(objectJson);
   }                 

function getGUID() {
    //DOCS : -http://guid.us/GUID/JavaScript
    function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
        var guid = ('svg_id_' + S4() + S4() + "_" + S4() + "_4" + S4().substr(0, 3) + "_" + S4() + "_" +            S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
    return guid;
}
</script>
```